# Android - passing data between threads

Tags: android, multithreading, pipeline

I need to pass a huge amount of data (raw bytes) between threads - listener thread and another thread that deals with the data manipulation. Whats the best and fastest way to do that?

Comment: Your question is too vague to provide a specific answer. Since you seem to want some sort of piping, take a look [PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html). That is as specific as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out it really depends on the task you have. I would suggest using a [Message](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/os/Message.html). For example if one of your threads is a producer of said byte[] data and the other is the consumer you may have something of the sorts:

```
public class ProducerThread extends Thread{
    byte[] data;

    public void run(){
        while (isRunning){
            Looper.prepare(); 
            data = someMethodToGetYourByteData(); 
            Message dataToSend = Message.obtain();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putByteArray("data", data);
            dataToSend.setData(bundle);
            if (ConsumerThread.mHandler!=null){  
               ConsumerThread.mHandler.sendMessage(dataToSend);
            }
            Looper.loop();  
         }
     }
```

and your consumer thread:

```
public class ConsumerThread extends Thread{
    public static Handler mHandler;  
    byte[] data;

    public void run(){
       while (running){
          Looper.prepare();
          mHandler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                mHandler.obtainMessage();
                data = msg.getData().getFloatArray("data");
                doSomethingWithData(data);
           };
         }
         Looper.loop();
      }
```

Keep in mind though that this may not be the best pattern to use, as many elsewhere on SO point out that it is not the best idea to extend a Thread, but it generally depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say the two threads are T1 and T2. Let us say we implement them using separate AsyncTasks A1 and A2. Now execute A2 from the onPostExecuteMethod of A1 passing necessary parameters to the execute method. This works fine because onPostExecute method runs in foreground and with respect to ui thread so that the A2 is executed only when A! has finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

Since your talking about large amounts of data. The best way is to wrap your byte[] in an Object. You can do your own custom class but most people use [ByteBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) because it already has a good manipulation API and can be used with the Java NIO sub-system.